# Jvectormap map not loaded in reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jvectormap

I have downloaded & imported all jvectormap js libraries in  at index.html. But no map is being displayed. However, there is no error related to the map. Did I import the js files in the correct way? This is my first reactjs project so I'm unfamiliar with reactjs.

[image]

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <meta content="Premium Multipurpose Admin & Dashboard Template" name="description" />
    <meta content="Themesdesign" name="author" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />    
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link href="assets/js/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
    <link href="assets/css/app.min.css" id="app-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/@fullcalendar/bootstrap/main.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.css" type="text/css">
    
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jvectormap/map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Index.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ApexChart from "../apexcharttt";
import { Helmet, HelmetProvider } from "react-helmet-async";
import worldMapConfig from "../jvectormap";
import $ from 'jquery';

export default function Index() {
  return (   
              <div className="col-xl-4">
              <div className="card">
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h4 className="header-title mb-4">Sales by State</h4>

                  <div id="world-map-markers" style={{ height: "230px" }}></div>
```

[image]